# choosing superclass for my project

Tags: java, inheritance, uml

I have been given an assignment for university where i have to read from a pdf file and print to it as well. The coding part of the assignment is straight forward enough; the only trouble is that I don't know what I could make as the superclass at the top of my inheritance chart.

Would I be right in making it a "create GUI" class which contains all the basic components such as the frame, the container, the font, and the button size and adding the methods to create instances of that class, or is that a totally useless class?

Comment: Why do you feel that you must create a "super" class at all? What problem is inheritance going to solve here? Why not instead concentrate on dividing out separate concerns -- your program logic from  your program GUI from the interaction between the two.

Comment: Well at the very top of the inheritance model you've usually got this class called "Object". I'd stick with that one.

Comment: cheers for the sarcasm chris helped greatly :) 
and i didn't think about not including inheritance at all, the way weve been taught it was that it was needed in all programs

Comment: @RoyJames: Inheritance is needed where it is useful and helpful. And if you were telling us that you were going to create a GUI that say demonstrated 3 different encryption/decryption schemes, I'd suggest that you first create an interface that each en/de class could inherit to standardize its interface to a shared one, but here for your current project, I think it best to avoid using inheritance for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please do not use inheritance at all if you can help it!**

Am I a technophobe? No.  Do I have repressed child/parent issues? Maybe, but that's another post.

Creating an inheritance relationship is not one that should be done lightly, if at all.  The main reason you need to create a new parent is if you need to describe the behaviour or attributes of a new *category* of objects from a general point of view.  The idea of inheriting because you want to specialize (vehicle/car) is really meant to give students an idea for why the feature is in the language i.e. a way to grasp the concept, not an example of the logic used to decide when it is needed.

From a previous discussion of [why the "vehicle/car' example is extremely flawed](http://codewright.blogspot.com/2009/01/identity-crisis.html):

Summary
1) Inheritance is a complex topic
2) Using a simple example to introduce a complex topic is admirable
3) Using an incorrect example creates students who, among other possibilities, try to extend the example and become confused or have a false sense of their understanding of the subject.
4) Using a bad example in class materials is inexcusable for a teacher who claims they understand the subject and who care about what the students get out of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of a superclass as being a generic form of your subclass.

For instance, a steak is a type of food. You could have Food as your superclass and Steak as a subclass of it.

In your project, does it make sense for everything in your project to inherit from this gui class?

It may not be necessary for all your objects to inherit from 1 thing.